# Why do I need to cast the argument of algorithm remove()?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, reference

I am trying to delete the consecutive duplicate characters from a string such as `"helloworld"` and delete all occurrences of the duplicate character. In this case, it is `'l'`, so the new string should be `"heoword"`. I have written the code like this:

```
#include <algorithm> 
#include <string>
#include <iostream>  

using namespace std; 

int main() { 
  string s = "helloworld"; 
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) { 
    if (s[i] == s[i+1]) { 
      s.erase(remove(s.begin(), s.end(), s[i]), s.end()); // PROBLEM
      cout << s << endl; // printing `heowrld`, instead of `heoword`
    } 
  }
  return 0;  
}
```

The code above doesn't work unless I cast `s[i]` like `(char)s[i]`. I looked up the operator `[]` for the string and it is returning the reference to the character at position. The `remove` method also accepts `const T& val` as parameter for character to be replaced. Since both of them are of the same type, why can't I just put in `s[i]` as argument to the `remove` method?

p.s. This is not homework problem. By casting the `s[i]` in `remove`, I can get correct output but I would like to know why I need to cast `s[i]`.

Comment: What is the exact compiler error?

Comment: This is probably homework, and thus forbidden by instructor fiat, but [take a look at `std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique)

Comment: @NathanOliver I am not getting any error but the output is `heowrld` instead of `heoword`.

Comment: You're post is missing a [mcve]

Comment: Can't duplicate the compiler error. http://ideone.com/VjKZCM.

Comment: @pseudo Your question is about requiring casting, and [this example shows that is not the case](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1837f9c1379ebbf3).  Also, I hope you're checking for an empty string before executing that loop.  An empty string puts you in la-la land if you try to execute that loop.

Comment: Please provide a complete source code, with all the variable declarations in place, the right includes, and at least a function definition...something we can at least compile and test.

Comment: @pseudo Is that not the correct output? `heowrld` has no duplicate chars, whereas `heoword` has a duplicate `o` and is missing the `l`. Or should the output be `heoworld`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know what the problem is here but without editing the question with a [mcve] there is not much I can do.

Comment: Shouldn't the print be outside of the loop?

Comment: @Justin I don't think it matters since there is only one consecutive duplicate in the `helloworld`, which is `ll`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is your moving the value to remove out from under yourself.  Lets look at

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int a = 5, b = 10;
    int & ref = a;
    std::cout << "a: " << a << " b: " << b << " ref: " << ref << "\n";
    std::swap(a, b);
    std::cout << "a: " << a << " b: " << b << " ref: " << ref << "\n";
}
```

If you run it you will get

```
a: 5 b: 10 ref: 5
a: 10 b: 5 ref: 10
```

and as you can see `ref` doesn't move to now follow `b` but stays with `a` (as it should) and prints `a`'s new value.

We are seeing the same thing with

```
s.erase(remove(s.begin(), s.end(), s[i]), s.end());
```

Since `s[i]` is a reference to an element in the string its value gets changed as remove swaps the elements around.  So it removes both `l`'s and then it also removes the last `o` since `o` is moved into the same position that `l` used to occupy but it only does so after it passed the first `o` in the string.

The reason casting "fixes" this is because now you are no longer referring to an element of the string.  You create a temporary variable and you use that variables value to remove the `l`'s.